# Relacion de llave foranea con llave primaria

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Me ocurre algo que para mi es muy particular nunca antes lo habia visto asi que no se como podria llamarle a ese error. Si alguno de ustedes pudiese arrojarme luz sobre el tema se lo agradezco enormemente.

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas con cardinalidad 1:1

```
tablaUsuarios
   **idUsuario**  ---> llave primaria
   tipoDocumento
   docUsuario
   otrosDatos
```

y la tabla

```
tablaEmpresas
   **idEmpresa** ---> llave primaria
   nombreEmpresa
   administradorEmpresa --->llave foranea
```

En la tabla empresas, el administrador de la empresa que tiene la llave foranea apunta al administrador de la misma. Hasta ahi creo que todo ok

**El problema viene cuando voy a registrar una empresa y quiero asociarla a una determinado usuario.** En el momento de agregarla uso phpmyadmin y en el campo administrador de empresa , en lugar de aparecer el listado del id de usuarios me aparece el listado de tipos de documentos.

He revisado con wl workbench y con el mimso phpmyadmin y veo la relacion entre las tablas de la manera que la explico. Incluso en el MER de workbench me aparece la relación como debe ser. No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas gracias

=======//==================//===============

El create de las tablas es el siguiente seria usuarios y colegios. El ultimo campo de colegios debe apuntar el pk de la tabla usuarios

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colegios`.`usuarios` (
  `usuario_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario_tipo_doc` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_num_doc` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_telefono` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_celular` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_ciudad` INT NOT NULL,
  `usuario_correo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_clave` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usuario_id`),
  INDEX `llave_ciudad_idx` (`usuario_ciudad` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `usuario_correo_UNIQUE` (`usuario_correo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `llave_ciudad`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_ciudad`)
    REFERENCES `colegios`.`ciudades` (`ciudad_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colegios`.`colegios` (
  `colegio_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `colegio_nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `colegio_ciudad` INT NOT NULL,
  `colegio_nit` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `colegio_direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `colegio_especialidad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `colegio_descripcion` TEXT NULL,
  `colegio_foto` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `colegio_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `colegio_web` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `colegio_telefono` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `colegio_fax` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `administrador_colegio_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`colegio_id`),
  INDEX `ciudad_colegio_idx` (`colegio_ciudad` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_colegios_usuarios1_idx` (`administrador_colegio_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `ciudad_colegio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`colegio_ciudad`)
    REFERENCES `colegios`.`ciudades` (`ciudad_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `admin_colegio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`administrador_colegio_id`)
    REFERENCES `colegios`.`usuarios` (`usuario_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Y como es el create de las tablas?

Comment: Esto pasa en cualquier base? o si lo haces en una base vacia no pasa?

Comment: Solo me pasa en esta, la borro y al crearla me pasa esto, la elimino y al crearla otra vez igual y la verdad es la primera vez que me ocurre.

Comment: y probaste en otra base de datos.. no es esta que estas trabajando..

Comment: Si te refieres a crear estas dos tablas en otra base de datos ? eso no lo he hecho. El 95% de las veces lo que hago es usar el workbench y desde el MER que me hago alli , generar el codigo con forward Engineer.  Usare el  codigo y creare una base de datos solo con estas dos tablas a ver que ocurre, quiza otra tabla mas arriba sea el problema aunque lo dudo porque las demas tablas van bien, solo el problema me lo generan estas dos.

Comment: por eso te decia.. como esta, tu error no es reproducible..

Comment: Despues de varios dias con el problema he notado varias cosas
Las colum de documento las puse de ultima en la tabla, despues LAS CAMBIE DE POSICION. Hasta alli todo normal. He quitado las dos columnas y todo ok. Al crearlas, quedan al final y todo OK sin embargo al cambiarlas de posición con workbench o con phpmyadmin se jode todo y la otra tabla con esta me muestra los datos que no son. He notado eso, y me surge la duda en otras ocasiones he movido columnas en la tabla y no ha pasado nada, Sabrias algo al respecto? o al moverlas arriba o abajo existe algun fallo en el SGBD que pasé por alto?

Comment: O que estoy haciendo mal en este caso ?

Comment: Sera algun bug del manejador de base de datos que estas usando? No deberian ser posicionales. NUNCA

Comment: Es posible ,  asi que lo que hare sera dejarlas al final de la tabla y ya porque tampoco me afecta el rendimiento de la aplicacion.... tampoco estoy haciendo el software del transborador espacial asi que eso no deberia afectar.

Comment: La posicion de las columnas nunca afecta el rendimiento de la db. El motor guarda los datos como mas le conviene, y los muestra como le pedis... no tiene nada que ver la posicion. si otras cosas.